# Amazon SQS Exception

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-sqs

I want to use SQS (production) to send mail in queue but it gives me exception error.

> Exception: Missing required client configuration options: version: (string) A "version" configuration value is required. Specifying a version constraint ensures that your code will not be affected by a breaking change made to the service. For example, when using Amazon S3, you can lock your API version to "2006-03-01". Your build of the SDK has the following version(s) of "sqs": * "2012-11-05" You may provide "latest" to the "version" configuration value to utilize the most recent available API version that your client's API provider can find. Note: Using 'latest' in a production application is not recommended. A list of available API versions can be found on each client's API documentation page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/index.html. If you are unable to load a specific API version, then you may need to update your copy of the SDK.

My code is

```
require(Config::get('paths.storage') . "sqs/aws-autoloader.php");
use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;


$client = SqsClient::factory(array(
                'key' => 'my-key',
                'secret' => 'sec-key',
                'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ));

$result = $client->createQueue(array('QueueName' => 'my-queue'));
    $queueUrl = $result->get('QueueUrl');
    $client->sendMessage(array(
        'QueueUrl' => $queueUrl,
        'MessageBody' => 'An awesome message!',
    ));

$result = $client->receiveMessage(array(
        'QueueUrl' => $queueUrl,
    ));

    foreach ($result->getPath('Messages/*/Body') as $messageBody) {
        // Do something with the message
        echo $messageBody;
    }
    die;
```

Error occured on: `SqsClient::factory`

Answer (score 4):

The exception gives you the reason. You need to specify the API version to use:

```
$client = SqsClient::factory(array(
            'version' => '2012-11-05',
            'key' => 'my-key',
            'secret' => 'sec-key',
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
));
```